# How do we load and resize image using tensorflow?

Tags: image, resize, tensor

I have just downloaded the dataset *caltech101* and I want to resize the image into the shape of (200,300,3). As I have read, I first need to convert the image into a tensor and then resize it using `tf.image.decode_jpeg`. But I don't know how to start from scratch with an image and turn it to a tensor.

*(I'm a beginner in learning machine learning)*

Answer (score 0):

To load an image using TensorFlow, first decode it like so:

`image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(...)`

To resize it, use the image from the code above, like so:

`resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [299, 299])`

You can find more on their API documents [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/).